# how can i optimize and bundling js files easiy of hot towel installed in asp.net mvc solution?

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, hottowel, sammy.js

I have hot towel template installed inside my asp.net mvc project. how can i optimize and bundle the js files with .net optimizer dlls in the app folder so requirejs work as it is?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Durandal, you can optimize the requirejs related javascript files using `Weyland`.
This tool is created to optimize your `main.js` which is heart of your `SPA`.
After using `Weyland` there will be a `main-built.js` which contains all required `javascript` files in it.

You can find more detail [here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Building-with-Weyland/).